# Delete the data in core data model of xcode in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I built a model with one entity called "user" with several attributes. And then I store three users' information in such entity. Now I create a button "reset" to delete all three users information permanently but keep the data model in SWIFT language. I tried but got error:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

which happened in var storeURL declaration line. Below are my code:

```
@IBAction func deleteIterm(){
var store:NSPersistentStore = NSPersistentStore()
    var storeURL:NSURL = store.URL 
    var storeCoordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator()
    storeCoordinator.removePersistentStore(store, error: nil)
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(storeURL.path, error: nil)
}
```

Where is the problem and how to solve that? Besides, is there any way to delete its corresponding sqlite file by hand?

Comment: Why do you cast `store.URL` to `NSURL`? Its already an `NSURL`.

Comment: Okey,I delete it, but it still did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `NSPersistantStore` and trying to access its `URL`, which isn't set up yet. You are also creating a new `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` which again, is not even initialized with a store.

What you are most likely trying to accomplish is to delete an existing `NSPersistentStore`. You should grab it like this:

```
@IBAction func deleteIterm(){
    var storeCoordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = /* Your already existing NSPersistantStoreCoordinator */
    var store:NSPersistentStore = storeCoordinator.persistantStores[0] as NSPersistantStore
    var storeURL:NSURL = store.URL 
    storeCoordinator.removePersistentStore(store, error: nil)
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(storeURL.path, error: nil)
}
```

If you are using the core data stack provided by Xcode, you should be able to access the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` through the `appDelegate`.

Comment: It works! I have a further question about this:in my program, I found once I set the data model and compile and run, I cannot modify the model(add/delete attributes or entities) again. If I do , the error will be "(lldb)" and program aborts. The reason is "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create". Even I used your solution to delete the store, it still does not work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you are modifying the model, usually you should delete the app from your device before debugging again. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried but this way does not work. In your code, why do you only remove store as persistantStores[0], but not all of them? what information in each persistantstores element? I will try remove everything in persistantstores.